# How can I load an npm package into Node REPL?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, read-eval-print-loop

How can I load npm packages into a Node REPL session?

Similarly, how can I load npm packages into a Node command line script?

I'm interested in being able to do this both via `require` and `import` - but either one will be acceptable.